# Service account doesn't get the quota from Google one

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

One friend of mine subscribed to Google one and granted permission to me use the storage, the problem is when i'm using a service account to upload a file to google drive, the storage shows as 15GB and don't let me upload more than that, is there anyway to grant the storage from my account to the service account?

I couldn't find anything related to Google one, any direction would help.

**Edit**: I used OAuth2, it isn't the best alternative, but I really don't want to go more into this.

Answer (score 1):

Service accounts are dummy users they have their own drive account but there is no way to extend the allotted space to that account.

Storage is based upon an account.  If you want to use the storage of a standard gmail user with a service account.  Then the service account needs to be uploading to that drive account.

Have your friend share a directory on their drive account with the service account. Then when you upload files make sure to set the parents id to that of the folder your uploading to.

Comment: I'm sharing my folder to the Service Account, but still i'm having problems with the quota.
"The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded."

Comment: Okay, this is something I have seen before.   When the file is first uploaded it checks that the user has space, that user being the service account.   Then the file is moved over to the drive folder and when you change the owner of the file its first there that the storage space is that of the owner of the directory.   I actually cant 100% remember if the space is deducted from the service account when the file is in the folder or not.

Comment: So, there isn't really any fix to solve?

Comment: make sure to clear out any files on the service account.   Make sure its not owner of the files.

Comment: How do I upload the fie with other owner? In my case, my real account, I couldn't find any documentation about that in nodejs drive api client